# References for $\Gamma$-convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, calculus-of-variations

There are two books (that I know of) on $\Gamma$-convergence, including "An Introduction to $\Gamma$-convergence" by del Maso, and "A Handbook of $\Gamma$-convergence" by Andrea Braides.

There is also a lecture series "$\Gamma$-convergence for Beginners" by Braides.

How do these compare?